# Cannot connect to Real VNC server with vncdotool api (hanging on method execution)

Tags: python, windows, vnc

Trying to connect to a RealVNC server with the vncdotool api but all it does is hang when executing a method.

Python version 3.7.4
vnctooldo 1.0.0
Windows 10
VNC Server 5.3.1

I've tried all RealVNC server authentication methods and insured RealVNC viewer is RAW encoding. I've also tried the command line vncdotool with the same hanging result.

```
from vncdotool import api

# connect to myvncserver.com on port 5902 (two colons needed)
client = api.connect('xx.xx.xxx.xx::5900')

client.timeout = 60

try:
    client.captureScreen('screenshot.png')
except TimeoutError:
    print('Timeout when capturing screen')
```